# Why bootstrap Select Box view is different with different browser

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap select box view is different in chrome and Mozilla. Why this is different View occurs and how can i fix this..

The view looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pycSW.jpg) image.

Chrome view is better.I want this view for all kind of browser.

Comment: Apparently the problem is logged within the Bootstrap community and hope they will provide a fix in v4. You can also look at the workaround mentioned here. [Bootstrap Github Repo](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/16201)

Answer (score 0):

A quick answer is down to each of the browsers using different render engines.

google normalize.css > normalize.css try's to render all elements consistently across all browsers.

A tip. load normalize before your otehr styles else the normalize will override your custom/main style sheet.